# Alternatives to port forwarding to get to a computer on my LAN from Internet

Tags: raspberry-pi, portforwarding, iot

I am planning a "IoT" project and my big problem so far is to install a RaspberryPi on a LAN, but accessible from the Internet, without making port forwarding, or Hamachi, or NGROK. The idea is to create a product that works "Out of the box".

The RaspberryPi have a web service running, listening for requests, and also will be sending HTTPRequest to populate a database with information.

Thanks for the help.

(Sorry for my english...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into UPnP.  I think there is a way for your device to tell your home router that it provides some service, and the home router will set up port forwarding automatically if it supports UPnP.

Comment: Thank you David, you answer is just **perfect**.

Comment: Do you think that using a VPN is a more professional way of doing this? I'm just seeing options.

Comment: I don't really see a reason to use a VPN except perhaps that it takes care of the authentication for you so you don't need to do that on your device.  But overall it's less convenient.

Comment: I thought that maybe adding all the RPi to my private VPN I can directly access them through IP Address. Sorry if it is a terrible idea, but I thought that LOL.